# Amazon S3 to Amazon Glacier custom vault

Tags: amazon-s3, cloud, cloud-storage, amazon-glacier

So I was researching about Amazon Cloud services and how to backup all my personal infrastructure to the cloud -btw it's really amazing what Amazon has achieved on this field-.

I started looking into S3 storage + Amazon Glacier automatic migration, that would give me high availability for recent files and high durability at low cost per GB for older files.

I followed this steps:

- Create a new bucket with S3
- Create a new vault with Glacier
- Create a new lifecycle rule, to transfer files to Glacier after 365 days and delete them from S3 after 400 days.

Here is my question. There is nowhere to specify on which vault you would like to copy your S3 bucket files into, so I don't exactly know what is going to happen when the rule is activated. Both bucket and vault are on the east-2 (Ohio) server. A new vault will to be created?. It will default to my only created vault?.

Comment: **Do not use this policy.**  It will not do what you expect, because you have not understood all the implications of these rules.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot yes, I'm deactivating the policy now. I didn't know that the Glacier storage was included as an abstract low cost solution on S3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot specify a vault.

Think of S3 as a customer of Glacier.  They have their own Glacier accounts -- they don't use *your* vaults.

> Although the objects are stored in Amazon Glacier, these remain Amazon S3 objects that you manage in Amazon S3, and you cannot access them directly through Amazon Glacier.
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-class-intro.html#sc-glacier

There is also more information in that sentence than meets the eye.  Configuring a lifecycle policy to delete the objects "from S3" removes them from Glacier.

S3's Glacier storage class allows you to store objects at Glacier pricing, while still having access to the object metadata through S3 -- they are still S3 objects.